# Crystal Report print option makes the report misaligned

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am generating a Crystal Report in ASP .NET. The report is generating fine. Here is the report view.

[image]

Problem occurs when I press print in Crystal Report. It ask for login details I selected integrated security. After that its becomes a mess. Screenshot:

[image]

After that the report becomes misaligned. Screenshot:

[image]

I searched about it without any luck. How can I keep the correct alignment of the report?

**EDIT:**

Code for showing the report:

```
    private void ViewReport(DateTime date) // This function for individual Customers
    {
        DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
        dtTable.TableName = "Command1";
        Daily_attendance_rpt rptAtd = new Daily_attendance_rpt();
        DataRow dataRow1;
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Emp_name", typeof(String));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Designation", typeof(String));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Dept", typeof(String));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Branch", typeof(String));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Entry_time", typeof(System.TimeSpan));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Exit_time", typeof(System.TimeSpan));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(String));
        dtTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(String));
        var rport = from att in db.Attendance_tables
                    join emp in db.Emp_infos on att.Login_id equals Convert.ToInt32(emp.Emp_ID)
                    where att.Date == date
                    select new
                    {
                        att.Id,
                        emp.Emp_name,
                        emp.ID,
                        emp.Branch,
                        emp.Designation,
                        emp.Dept,
                        att.Entry_time,
                        att.Exit_time,
                        att.Status,
                        att.Date
                    };
        foreach (var rt in rport)
        {
            dataRow1 = dtTable.NewRow();
            //dataRow1["Id"] = rt.Id;
            dataRow1["Emp_name"] = rt.Emp_name;
            dataRow1["Designation"] = rt.Designation;
            dataRow1["Dept"] = rt.Dept;
            dataRow1["Entry_time"] = rt.Entry_time;
            dataRow1["Exit_time"] = rt.Exit_time;
            dataRow1["Status"] = rt.Status;
            dataRow1["Date"] = rt.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            dataRow1["Branch"] = rt.Branch;
            dtTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1);
        }
        rptAtd.SetDataSource(dtTable);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptAtd;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code. how do you show crystal report? How do you assign LogOnInfo to crystal report?

Comment: @Wulworine> I am not assigning any logOnInfo in crystal report. This report is same as you sent last time.

Comment: Then how do you show the crystal report? Something like using `crystalReport1.Database.SetDataSource(ds)`?

Comment: I suppose the issue here is that in the print view, the date formats are broken.. Are you setting the date formats for print view somewhere in your code?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan > No, I didn't set any print option in my code. I am using the default option.

Answer (score 0):

For asking log-in detail, you have to set credential in your code as

[VS2010 Crystal Reports ask for login when sending a Dataset via code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069591/vs2010-crystal-reports-ask-for-login-when-sending-a-dataset-via-code)

For printing mismatch, the similar issue I found for [crystal report 13.0.4 version](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting/Crystal_Reports/Q_27930663.html).

What I suggest you can try with setting the properties of one label. when its not overlap, then you apply the same for others. 
I forgot the properties, by right click "can-grow"  will help you.

If you donot have the same version, then check this link.

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1673336